# How to remove single quote from comma seprated integer values

Tags: javascript, casting

I m getting result as `'2,3,7'` as result from database, now I want to remove `'` (single quote) from the string and get output as `2,3,7`

My intention is to use this values as array like `[2,3,7]`. But due to it is string it is storing like `['2,3,7']`.

I have tried to convert it to an integer using `parseInt` but it is giving me first index value i.e 2 in this case.

So basically input is like `'2,3,7'` and expected output is like `2,3,7`.

**Updation** :
I can see many peoples are considering input as "'2,3,7'", consider input as '2,3,7'.
Also I have one working solution for this :

```
var str = '2,3,7',finalOutput=[];
var splittedValues = str.split(",");
splittedValues.forEach((value) => {
    finalOutput.push(parseInt(value));
});
```

Is there any direct way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the output should be array? or string without single quote?

Comment: Yes Array......

Answer (score 2):

Using **Regex** `match()`

**DEMO**: https://regex101.com/r/JhTkVB/1

```js
var string1 = "'2,3,7'"
var string2 = "2,3,7"

console.log(string1.match(/\d+/g).map(Number));
console.log(string2.match(/\d+/g).map(Number));
```

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Now you can see that it works with both cases

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed that! I just went through the answers looking for the "' pattern. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do what you want is the following:

```js
let str = '2, 3, 7';
let yourArray = str.split(',').map(Number);
console.log(yourArray);
```

This splits by the comma and then uses the map function which converts each value in an array using the function given as argument and stores them in a new array. So in this case, the function `Number` is called thrice with the arguments `'2'`, `'3'` and `'7'`. `Number` is the constructor of the number object which also parses string to a number. The resulting array is then stored in `yourArray` which then has the value `[2, 3, 7]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove first and last characters.

```js
var string = "'2,3,7'",
    values = string.slice(1, -1);

console.log(values);
```

Comment: After the edit of OP, this answer has turned invalid because it tries to solve a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to remove the enclosing single quotes -

```js
var str = "'2,3,7'",
str = str.substring(1, str.length - 1)

console.log(str);

//If you need an array then

str = str.split(',').map(Number)

console.log(str);
```

Comment: If you want to remove a certain character from a string, target the character, instead of assuming it'll be there.

Comment: @Cerbrus Hey - Look at the question. It is not absolutely necessary to target the character in this context. Removing first and last is enough - and anything scanning the string is an overkill.

Comment: Yea, and the next project where anyone reading this wants to remove some characters from a string, they'll use this method again, even if their input may not be that predictable. Overkill? `replace` code isn't exactly a performance hog, and the code is arguably more readable.

Comment: Thinking about the next project during a removal of characters from a simple string is called "premature optimization". That is the worst of all programming evils. `replace` is too much for this scenario. Don't measure the length of a carrot when you want to slice off the top and bottom of it ;)

Comment: `replace` is too much if you want to remove a specific character from a string? It's what that function was made for!

Comment: It's not about a specific character. It is about the top and bottom.

Comment: After the edit of OP, this answer has turned invalid because it tries to solve a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per your update, it seems as though your input string is simply `'2,3,7'`. To convert this into an array of numbers, you can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) by encapsulating your string in square brackets like so:

```js
const str = '2,3,7';
const arr = JSON.parse(`[${str}]`);
console.log(arr); // [2, 3, 7]
```